# Why Should I use the var in php? Why does browser shows error when var is not defined? foreach loop shows invalid argument as well

Tags: php, backend, web-development-server

why does it shows undefined variables.
Undefined variable: classRooms.
Why should I use var in class properties instead of only using $ in php.

```
class School {

    var $teachersCount = 10;
    var $classRooms =20;

    function teachingHours(){
         $teacherHours = array();
         $teacherHours = $this->classRooms / $this->teachersCount;
         foreach ($teacherHours as $key => $hours) {
            $teacherHours = $teacherHours -$key;
            echo $teacherHours.''.$key;
         }

    }
}
```

Instantiating the School class

```
$school = new School();
echo $school-> classRooms;
echo"<br>";
echo $school -> teachersCount;
echo"<br>";
$school-> teachingHours();
```

Comment: `$teacherHours = $this->classRooms / $teachersCount;`

Comment: *"Why should I use var in class properties instead of only using $ in php"* - you **shouldn't** unless you're writing PHP that's about 10+ years out of date. Those are properties of the object and should be declared `public`, `protected` or `private` - see [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Because you are not encapsulating. Use public, private or protected. It will work